# Error in serializing NSNumber using JSONKIT

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, serialization, jsonkit

I'm getting `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I368_GPFLT)` when trying to serialize dictionary that contains `NSNumber` using `JSONKIT`

I got the exception in method called `jk_encode_add_atom_to_buffer` in the following line

```
void  *objectISA = (JK_EXPECT_F(workAroundMacOSXABIBreakingBug)) ? NULL : *((void **)objectPtr);
```

here is sample code i tried

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{@"StringKey":@"Value", @"NumberKey" : @5};
NSString* reqString = [dict JSONStringWithOptions:JKSerializeOptionNone error:&jsonError];
```

is there is any hint why I'm getting this error?

Comment: With the quoted line, I'm not surprised that it crashes, I'm surprised that it ever worked. What the hell are these guys doing? I'd strongly recommend using NSJSONSerialization.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you found out the answer to your problem as it's an old post, but I got the same error and I fixed it by using this version of JSONKit:

https://github.com/danielStokowski/JSONKit

Use this one instead of the old one and you will no longer have this error.

Comment: I used a workaround. I'll use your solution tomorrow and get back to you